# Protocol definition as `NotificationCenter` object?

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter

I have a protocol definition:

```
protocol Environment {
  var url: String {get}
}
```

I give it to the `NotificationCenter` as an object:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NotificationForEnvironmentChange, object: Environment)
```

But it does not show up in the object property of the function I assign to the selector for the `NotificationForEnvironmentChange`.

```
func environmentChange(sender: Notification) {
    guard let newEnvironment = sender.object as? Environment else {
        return
    }
    //Never gets the environment
}
```

Why?

Note: NotificationForEnvironmentChange is a `Notification` property I define like so:

```
let NotificationForEnvironmentChange = Notification.Name("NotificationForEnvironmentChange")
```

Comment: When you call `NotificationCenter.default.post`, pass an instance of a class that conforms to the protocol (maybe `self`?), not the protocol itself.